# Use appdata environment variable in csproj

Tags: c#, .net, csproj

I am trying to use appdata in my csproj file to copy a license file to appdata only when other devs are running in debug mode.

This is what I am trying in the after build section of the csproj file:

```
 <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
      <LicenseFile Include="..\..\..\..\utilities\FlexNet\Glass_Debug.lic"/>      
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(LicenseFile)" DestinationFiles="@(LicenseFile->'$(%AppData%)\CompanyName\SeismicInterpretation\%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
```

I am not getting an error and the project builds and runs fine except it does not copy the license file to my appdata folder.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try just using `$(AppData)`.  MSBuild makes Environment Variables available as standard MSBuild properties.