# MSBuild: How Get AppData Local Directory?

Tags: msbuild, appdata

I need help getting the AppData Local directory for MSBuild.

File Explorer:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%
```

C#:

```
System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
```

PowerShell:

```
$([System.Environment]::GetFolderPath("LocalApplicationData"))
```

I've tried the following four variations to get it for MSBuild:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AppDataLocalDir1>$([System.Environment]::GetFolderPath([System.Environment.SpecialFolder]::LocalApplicationData))</AppDataLocalDir1>
    <AppDataLocalDir2>$([System.Environment]::GetFolderPath([System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData]))</AppDataLocalDir2>
    <AppDataLocalDir3>([System.Environment]::GetFolderPath("LocalApplicationData"))</AppDataLocalDir3>
    <AppDataLocalDir4>([System.Environment]::GetFolderPath('LocalApplicationData'))</AppDataLocalDir4>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I feel that my syntax must be close, as this works to get the current date:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Today>$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString('yyyy.MM.dd'))</Today>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I have found sources that state that MSBuild can call `[System.Environment]::GetFolderPath`, but I cannot find any that show the syntax for passing in an argument.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I found the answer, which is to use `$(LocalAppData)`, which is based on this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23120542/10429. I'm leaving the question up, because the question about the calling syntax for .NET classes from MSBuild is still relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From "[Property Functions: GetFolderPath](http://sedodream.com/2011/03/21/PropertyFunctionsGetFolderPath.aspx)" the syntax for the enum for GetFolderPath is:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AppDataLocalDir>$([System.Environment]::GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData))</AppDataLocalDir>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thank you Jonathan -- this corrects my syntax for accessing the enum. I was also able to make use of $(LocalAppData), which seems to be practically undocumented.